# how to get the precise location of an overlay marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers

I have the following map, and the address I get when centering the camera with OnCameraIdleListener, but as you can see in the image you are getting the address of the center of the marker, not the bottom that is what you want.
I appreciate any suggestions. And sorry for my english

in the image the address should be "sucre ..." no L.Jaimes ......

```
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {

    Log.i(TAG, "onCameraIdle");
    LatLng position = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
    if (position != null) {
        mCurrentLocation.setLatitude(position.latitude);
        mCurrentLocation.setLongitude(position.longitude);
        retrieveAddress(position);
    }
}
```

My Map Fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:context="com.mobifire.edwin.mobifire.UserMaps" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvCurrentMarker"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_a_marker" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue with this type of UI with google maps. But I know you can achieve it by doing a trick.

a) First of all, I recommend you to use a [function of Projection](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) given by Google Map's Android SDK. I'm talking about `toScreenLocation(LatLng center)`. This property help us to get the exact Screen Point that correspond to our LatLng coordinate.  By using this approach, you can easily center your marker in the center of the projection of the Map, even if you set a Padding and reduce the visible part of the map.

Ok now, the interesting part, is to set the proper position of the drawable to be able to see it centered where it needs to be, and of course get the correct Address!!

b) Get the Height and Width of your view/drawable, and as the drawable is positioned in its center, you have to set a new position by this center. So in order to achieve it, you need to get the width size divided in two. This is because the reset of new position.

c) And finally move it up by the Height size and horizontally by the half of the width.

```
    //  a) Get center screenPoint.
    Point screenPoint = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(map.getCameraPosition().target);
    //  b) Get center position of drawable.
    int fixPlaceMarkerPointX = (imvCurrentMarker.getWidth() / 2);
    int fixPlaceMarkerPointY = (imvCurrentMarker.getHeight());
    //  c) Set new position for the marker.
    imvCurrentMarker.setY(screenPoint.y + fixPlaceMarkerPointY);
    imvCurrentMarker.setX(screenPoint.x - fixPlaceMarkerPointX);
```

d) I think there's another approach, and the easiest, but not cooler! haha
This is just, move with a negative margin by the total size of the height.
So you have a `50dp` as height, just give it a `top_margin = "-50dp"`.
One more thing, you can just put `centerInParent` in the marker Drawable.

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imvCurrentMarker"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_a_marker" />
```

I hope this helps!